# google maps iframe included address not displaying partial match map

Tags: google-geocoding-api

We are trying to use google map uri to add location map using iFrame.
We are able to see the google map uri is working fine on locating partial match address from browser but same is not working on including it on an iFrame.

Is there any way to get the partial match address on iFrame by using google maps uri to get the nearest match even the address is not matches exactly? like what we see on direct maps access?
Eg.,
If I access below uri on webbrowser, its showing the partial match with location
https://www.google.com/maps?q="Postfach 1130,D-85765 Unterföhring"&"output=embed"
[browserMap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYmIW.png)

But if we use the same on iFrame its not able to show instead showing full world map.
https://www.google.com/maps?q="Postfach 1130,D-85765 Unterföhring"&output=embed
[iFrameMap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAalR.png)

Comment: I believe the `"` shouldn't be used in the q parameter, also you should URL-encode your address string `Postfach%201130%2CD-85765%20Unterf%C3%B6hring`.

Comment: Its not a problem with encoding, we have some encoded addresses as well but they are not working with iframe included uri. Problem is only with Partial match addresses, other valid/exact match addresses are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Postfach, PO boxes, CEDEX, etc. are not supported by the Google Maps and APIs.

Even searching on google.com will show this, a search for "D-85765 Unterföhring" shows a map of that postal code, but a search for "Postfach 1130, D-85765 Unterföhring" shows no map.

Comment: Thanks miguev, yeah but we are able to see partial match on browser with same address, pls try this link on browser << https://www.google.com/maps?q="Postfach 1130,D-85765 Unterföhring"&"output=embed" >> its able to show the right map. But this partial match not working on iframe. Our issue is why the browser can able to display the partial match but not showing it on iframe.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the answer to that particular issue, but you can report issues with the Google Maps Embed API at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188814